# Alexa skill have user confirm slot values

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I'm building Alexa skills using Node.js in a lambda function and can't find any tutorials on the best way to confirm the data I have in the slots. I got to the point that all slots now have data but would like to have Alexa read back the request and get a confirmation from the user before proceeding. What's the best & proper way to do this?

At first I thought to use an emit with :elicitSlot but then I would need a new slot to do this and it looks very hackish.

for example:

```
if(all slots have a valid value){
this.emit(':elicitSlot','confirm',"You're request is .... with data .... is this correct?");
}
if(user confirmed data is valid){
// do something
}else{
// the data was not correct get the right data
}
```

Comment: For the whoie intent confirmation, check [here](https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/docs/ask-define-the-vui-with-gui#intent-confirmation). For only slot confirmation, check [here](https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/docs/ask-define-the-vui-with-gui#enable-slot-confirmation)

Comment: Thank you Sidmeister, can you turn your comment into an answer so I can approve it. Also can the confirmation for the skill and slots be fine tuned for example if one of the slots is something like a name and alexa knows 100% what name I said can it skip the confirmation. Or is confirmation an on off 100% of the time? I would like a gray area for confirming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the whole intent confirmation, check [here](https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/docs/ask-define-the-vui-with-gui#intent-confirmation). For only slot confirmation, check [here](https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/docs/ask-define-the-vui-with-gui#enable-slot-confirmation).

Also, for your followup question,

> can the confirmation for the skill and slots be fine tuned for example if one of the slots is something like a name and alexa knows 100% what name I said can it skip the confirmation?

Short answer - of course you can if you do not maintain the dialog. However, it's strongly discouraged to rely on that.

In order to maintain a dialog, you have to monitor `dialogState` attribute of the intent request, and as long as it's not in state `COMPLETED` send response with attribute `directives` as `[{'type': 'Dialog.Delegate'}]` to keep it flowing. You can maintain finer control of the dialog - consult [this doc](https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/docs/dialog-interface-reference#scenario-full-control). Moreover, you are strongly suggested to omit `outputSpeech` and `reprompt` in those responses, otherwise Alexa gets upset. Once dialog status is `COMPLETED`, you get `confirmationStatus` (for both Intent and slots) - SUCCESS(?)/DENIED/NONE. If the confirmation is not successful. I have seen multiple matches being sent as reply. However, when successful, only the matched slot value is returned.

P.S. I have had this weird issue. When Alexa is asking for confirmation for one slot value, if I deliberately decline twice in a row, it gives up and does nothing! Although, pretty much 99% of the time Alexa was spot on.

P.P.S. Turns out 2 attempts was a hard limitation from Alexa. This is supposed to be improved in next iterations.